# The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32 python POST

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I have an issue with the POST method in python.

My code :

```
url = "https://blablabla.com"
data = {
    "data1": "blalba",
    "data2": "12"
}

resp = requests.post(url, json=data)

print(resp.text)
```

My output is :

```
{"result":false,"data":null,"error":{"httpStatusCode":0,"errorMessages":null,"isError":false},"validationErrors":[{"field":"$.sicno","error":["The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.sicno | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 18."]}],"isError":true}
```

how can I handle it? Thank you.

Comment: this may be specific to your target URL.

Comment: Your error is that `data2`'s value in your dictionary is a string when it should be an int, double, whatever number type is appropriate. If you don't want to do that, change your API to allow string'd numbers and do the conversion in your backend.

Comment: `"12"` is a string, not a number. If `data2` is supposed to contain a number use `"data2":12`